# Is .htc file a good practice in older versions of IE for rounded corners like CSS3 has?

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I am trying to make the simple html button with rounder corner using CSS3 but for IE i am using .htc file for round curve, is the .htc file using is good habit or bad i am not able to judgment to use this .html file.

My another worries is that progressive enhancement allow to use .htc file or not.

Please also tell me if there are some disadvantages to use .htc file.

I am new to css3, help much appreciated.

Comment: Don't know if this is any better, but it's javascript only: http://www.ruzee.com/content/liquid-canvas

Comment: Personally I think you shouldn't use any of these things at all. Use the CSS3 rounded borders and if users have an older version of IE the border are just not round and not fancy. And perhaps the "ugliness" will convince them to finally update their browser IMHO. Obviously only as long as it doesn't influence the functionality of your website, people with older versions (up to a limit) should be able to use your site, be it with less eye-candy.

Comment: @Bazzz - or you can implement it and make it look nice, but the slowness convinces them to upgrade.  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The disadvantage of those `.htc`-based solutions is that because they draw the corners using JavaScript and VML, they are *slow* (compared to browsers that have native `border-radius` support). However, you'll only usually notice this if you're using the effect extensively.

Unfortunately though, there isn't any *better method* to get rounded corners in older versions of IE (IE now supports `border-radius` in version 9):

- Images are a lot of work (you have to make new images for different radii)
- Pure JavaScript solutions doing things like making many `div`s to create the corners are an even slower solution.

What I would suggest is using [**CSS3PIE**](http://css3pie.com/) to make the rounded corners instead. This uses the same `.htc`/VML method, but it's an actively updated library doing it in the best way possible. Additionally, it provides support for more CSS3 eye-candy.

Comment: It isn't the .htc that makes it slow; it's the VML. But other all solutions have major issues, so the bottom line is: if you want rounded corners in IE<9, you need to use a VML-based solution. If it's important enough to you that you must have rounded corners then you'll just have to swallow the fact that it's slow. CSS3Pie is the best solution there is.

Comment: I agree with your comment, except that I didn't say the `.htc` itself makes it slow - read my first sentence carefully.

Comment: Yep. I was agreeing with you.  :)

Comment: @Spudley: I agree with your agreement :)

Comment: that's very agreeable of you  :)

Answer (score 0):

No, Its not a good practice, its a kind of hacking which make a bad impact on code and page performance.

.htc file force browser to artificially to draw the round corner using vml.

In this case you should use Progressive Enhancement, read this article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement

this term is best practice for all browser and devices.

Comment: It'll have a bad impact on page performance only insofar as the rounded corners will be rendered after other elements; that's not sufficiently bad to make this 'bad practice' given the lack of alternatives. And a .htc file is a form of progressive enhancement - and you're not suggesting another.