# How to implement "Rounded Corner on hover effect" in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, css, rounded-corners

I want to create a link with the rounded corner effect. 
However, the rounded corner effect will show while hover only. 
By using CSS3, it's working fine on mozilla, chrome and Safari, but not in IE.

Here my css

```
a {
color: black; background-color:#ddd;
text-align: center;font-weight: bold;
width:110px; height:25px;
padding: 10px; text-decoration:none;
}

.abc:hover {
background-color: lightblue;
-moz-border-radius: 15px; -webkit-border-radius: 15px; border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Here my html

```
<a href="#" class="abc">Button</a>
```

Comment: Beside that, I had try to insert external file like (ie-css3.htc) inside my css. It's working with div element, but not for hover element.
here my code

.abc:hover {
background-color: lightblue;
-moz-border-radius: 15px; -webkit-border-radius: 15px; border-radius: 15px; 
behavior: url(ie-css3.htc); /*for IE*/
}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Michael Rose says, IE8 and lower simply do not support CSS3 rounded corners.

There are a variety of workarounds to apply rounded corners in these versions of IE.

To my knowledge, the best of these workarounds is [**CSS3 PIE**](http://css3pie.com/).

See another relevant answer I wrote:

[Is .htc file a good practice in older versions of IE for rounded corners like CSS3 has?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471652/is-htc-file-a-good-practice-in-older-versions-of-ie-for-rounded-corners-like-css/5471776#5471776)

---

Edit in response to your edited comment: I'm reasonably sure CSS3 PIE supports `:hover` properly.

---

Edit 2:

I just tried it, this CSS works:

```
a {
    color: black; background-color:#ddd;
    text-align: center;font-weight: bold;
    width:110px; height:25px;
    padding: 10px; text-decoration:none;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}

.abc:hover {
    background-color: lightblue;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px; -webkit-border-radius: 15px; border-radius: 15px;
}
```

To make it work, I moved the `behavior` property to the `a` block instead of the `.abc:hover` block.

Comment: Link to download the file for PIE.htc
http://css3pie.com/PIE.htc
Just put together with ur html and css file. then you can use it! Cheer~

Comment: thirtydot: Thanks for answering this question. 
actually, don't know how many many hours, I had been workout to find a solution for this problem. Finally I got it~

Thousands of appreciates~ ^_^

Comment: No worries. I learned that CSS3 PIE does indeed work with `:hover`, something I hadn't tried yet.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply because rounded borders are only implemented in IE9 and not below.

Comment: But..Sometime it can work with external file like l(ie-css3.htc).

Answer (score 1):

You might check the compatibility with IE9, just add

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

to your page header and it's going to work, hopefully isA

Comment: You're welcome, BTW: you can mark it as an answer of the question by click on the true mark beneath the rating arrows :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will work for IE9

```
<div class="rounded" style="background:#ddd"></div>

.rounded {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  border:2px solid #404040;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```