# when using ie-css3.htc hover stop working for elements

Tags: css

```
.search .search_place li.search_button a { 
background: #017aa7; 
padding: 10px; 
color: #fff; 
text-decoration: none; 
font: normal normal bold 12px/1.5 "Arial", Helvetica, sans;
border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
behavior: url(ie-css3.htc);
z-index: 100;
position: relative;
}

.search .search_place li.search_button a:hover { 
background: #ffa63c; 
}
```

i am using this IE7 hack for rounded corners: http://code.google.com/p/box-shadow/downloads/detail?name=ie-css3.htc&can=2&q=

but when i am using this htc file hover stop working. Anyone have similar problems that :hover stop working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching to [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/).

It's an *actively maintained* project that, [amongst other things](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/), provides `border-radius` for older versions of IE.

[In my experience it supports `:hover` properly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618765/how-to-implement-rounded-corner-on-hover-effect-in-ie)